# Carbon add method

Tags: php, date, php-carbon

Certainly something trivial, but I'm stuck!

I have a start date initialized like this:

```
$startDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', '2024-02-01 08:00');
```

I add days to this date to get an end date:

```
$qtyDays = 25;
$endDate = $startDate->addDays($qtyDays);
```

What I don't understand is that the end date is calculated correctly. **But the start date contains the end date.**

How not to touch the start date ? Even though I read the Carbon doc, I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Maybe using the Immutable version of Carbon instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is not related to Carbon itself, as Carbon is just a wrapper for the PHP DateTime class, and as long as the PHP has DateTime & DateTimeImmutable, Carbon also do has the wrapper for both.:

> This class behaves the same as DateTimeImmutable except objects are modified itself when modification methods such as DateTime::modify() are called.

So you can use the `CarbonImmutable` like:

```
$startDate = CarbonImmutable::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', '2024-02-01 08:00');
$qtyDays = 25;
$endDate = $startDate->addDays($qtyDays);
```